# Set up Alarm Manager Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have been trying to set up an Alarm Manager and I cannot seem to get it working.

My AlertManager is as follows:

```
    public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 1000 * 30;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context
      .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
      Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
      PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,
      PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

      cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
    // InexactRepeating allows Android to optimize the energy consumption
      service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
       cal.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME, pending);
     }
```

CreateNotification method in AlertManager:

```
      public void createNotification(Context context, String msg, String  msgText, String msgAlert) {

      PendingIntent notificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, 
        new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

      NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setContentTitle(msg)
        .setTicker(msgAlert)
        .setContentText(msgText);

       mBuilder.setContentIntent(notificationIntent);
       mBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);
       mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

       NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
        context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        }
```

My Main Activity is as follows: showNotification method which is outside onCreate:

```
     public void showNotification(View view) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificBuilder = new        NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setContentTitle("message")
.setContentText("New Message")
.setTicker("Alert New Message");

  Intent moreInfoIntent = new Intent(this, MoreInfoNotification.class);

  TaskStackBuilder tStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

tStackBuilder.addParentStack(MoreInfoNotification.class);

  tStackBuilder.addNextIntent(moreInfoIntent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = tStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notificBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


      notificationManager =        (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);        
notificationManager.notify(notifId, notificBuilder.build());

   isNotificActive = true;
      }
```

Comment: What problem are you facing? Post your logcat.

Comment: Nothing happens when i press the Button Show Notification, linked to show notification method

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,
PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

I think you want to start `MainActivity`, but you created a `PendingIntent` that send a boardcast message (via `getBroadcast()` method). You should use `getActivity()` method of `PendingIntent`.